# Webpage rendering very differently on different browsers

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser, rendering

Like my title says, my webpage which has a couple position:relatives that look perfect in google chrome and firefox are offset in safari.
Is there a way in my css to counter-act this offset? I'm not even sure why it's happening.

Comment: if you don't show us the code (or at least an example of what you mean), we're not going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried using a css reset?

by using a reset you can set the margins and padding of all elements to 0. 0 is the one number that all browsers agree on...from there you will have to add margins and padding to the elements but you should achieve a consistent look in different browsers